# Why js frameworkss size so small comparing to jar files?

Tags: java, javascript, filesize

I'm just curious that why the js frameworks' size is so small( usually under 100k ), but if you see some of the java framework packages( the jar files ) normally takes over several megabytes, or even hundred megabytes. 
What's making them so different?

Comment: It's not really comparable, Jar files are (lowly compressed) Zip files, which have overheads, can contain additional resources, like images and language files and contain binary data.  A js file is a text file...

Comment: maybe you're on of those who don't know the difference: `javascript != java`

Comment: Hi Joshua, I know the difference between javascript and java or the fact they aren't a little relevant at all. But I just have the question that why js can be so small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, Javascript frameworks are just Javascript files (it's just plain text without binaries unlike JARs) so they are just packaged as is.

Second, they are usually uglified and compressed so that they could be sent to the client efficiently whereas JAR files just reside in the server so its size is less of an issue.